# Android and Firebase Firestore: Wait nested tasks to complete

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, task

I think it is a simple problem, I have 3 main collections: collection_A, collection_B and collection_C. The problem is: I need a document "A" of collection_A. The document "A" contains an array attribute "collection_B_uids", after get document "A" I need to get every document of collection_B that is in collection_B_uids, so I did this:

```
public Task foo() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collection_A").document("A").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(docA -> {
            List<String> collection_B_uids = docA.get("collection_B_uids");
            // ...
            for (String uid : collection_B_uids) {
                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collection_B").document(uid).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(docB -> {
                        // ...
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

Works fine, but then I need to access some documents of collection_C by another array attribute in every document of collection_B. I want to use the return of `foo` like that:

```
foo().addOnSuccessListener(...)
```

And that final `addOnSuccessListener` should be executed after all nested tasks are completed. I already use `Tasks.whenAllSuccess` inside the main Task, but it didn't worked.

My guesses:

a) create a recursive function using 2 listener at time;

b) use `continueWithTask` or `continueWith` (prefered);

c) create a global `AsyncTask` an then use `Tasks.await` (please, don't).

Ps: I'm not english native

Comment: the returned Task is the first one. so if you want to wait for all to finish you have to return the last Task (last onSuccessListener)

Comment: And how can I return it? If i create a `Task lastOne = null`, set it value inside any success listener, my return would be null.

Comment: Why do you say "it didn't worked" when you have used `Tasks.whenAllSuccess`? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo because `Tasks.whenAllSuccess` takes as argument an array os tasks, but most of that tasks are created inside another Task. Take my example, I have a main Task "get document of collection A", all tasks "get document of collection B" are created inside success listener of task A, making impossible to "return task A" when all tasks "B" success, because they should be in an array of tasks that is created outside task A, and all tasks are async, so the return of `Tasks.whenAllSuccess` occurs when task A is succeed, not when tasks B are succeed. Kinda confusing, hope you understand